# Add a badge in a tabview

Tags: nativescript

I have a page in my mobile application where I have 2 tabs : one is for the notifications. I'd like to know how I could put a badge telling how many unread notifications I have.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do this, for now, is by using the native property of the TabView and setting a badgeValue on the tabItem.

For iOS it would be something like this:

```
var myTabView = page.getViewById("myTabView");
var tabItem = myTabView.ios.tabBar.items[0];
tabItem.badgeValue = "5";
```